# Clarification on a Inverse modulo exercise

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Find integers $x$ and $y$ such that $49x + 100y = 1$. Which, if either, is the inverse of $49$, modulo $100$?

I know the answer to this is $x = 49$  and $y = -24$, but how do I arrive at that?

The argument starts with:

$$100 = 1(100) + 0(49)$$

$$49 = 0(100) + 1(49)$$

$$2 = 1(100) - 2(49)$$

The last step is:

$$1 = -24(100) + 49(49)$$

I just can't understand where the $-24$ and $49(49)$ came from.

Comment: Look gcd (100,49)=1 and you can express 1 as linear combination of 100 and 49. Hope so you know how to write that if not let me know i will show you the calculations.

Comment: I do not. Do you mind showing the calculations?

Comment: Not at all, wait I will write it up.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I think this will help you, if not you can ask for clarifications.

Comment: let the equation be ax+ by =c , you can solve this type of equation iff gcd(a,b) | c , and process of  finding solution is exactly same first write gcd(a,b) as a linear combination of a and b and multiply with appropriate integer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we begin by finding the gcd of $(49, 100)$ using [Euclidean Division Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Procedure), despite already knowing what it will be. (They're coprime)
\begin{align*}
100&=49\times2+2 \\
49&=2\times24+1 \\
24&=24\times1+0
\end{align*}
So, $1$ is the gcd of $100$ and $49$, but you already knew this.

And now, we keep substituting, from the last step upto the first:
\begin{align*}
1&=49-2\times24 &\text{From the second equation}\\
&=49-(100-49\times2)\times24 &\text{From the first equation}\\
&=49-24\times100+48\times49 \\
\text{So,} \\
1&=49\times49+(-24)\times100 &\text{And there you have it!} \\
\end{align*}

So, 
$$x=49, y=-24$$